# PCIe DMA for Altera FPGA

Tags: alter, dma

We have a Cyclone5 FPGA from Altera and we want to do DMA from the RAM of the computer to the FPGA and vice-versa.

I have already read a post entitled "How to write CPU's DMA address to FPGA (PCIe Endpoint)?" but it did not give me enough information to write code to do this.

Can anyone help us?

Comment: Is [the documentation](https://www.altera.com/support/support-resources/design-examples/soc.html) of no help?

Comment: This question would be better on [Electrical Engineering](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).